# Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type BaseCellData

Tags: swift, generics

I get this error when building my Swift code:

```
Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '(BaseCellData, at: Int)' on the row
```

when I run the following code:

```
public class CellDataCollection<T: BaseCellData> {
    private var data = [T]()

    func populate(from data: [T]) {
        self.data = data
        let firstObjectIsHeader = data.first?.isHeader ?? false
        if !firstObjectIsHeader {
            let newEmptyHeader = BaseCellData(isEmptyHeader: true)
            self.data.insert(newEmptyHeader, at: 0)
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I figured since T is a BaseCellData it should be ok to add a new instance of BaseCellData to an array of T. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a constructor to all subclasses that implement BaseCellType. This allowed me to create an instance of T instead of BaseCellType:

```
public class CellDataCollection<T: BaseCellData> {
func dataWithLeadingEmptyHeader(from data: [T]) -> [T] {
        var newData = data
        let firstObjectIsHeader = data.first?.isHeader ?? false
        if !firstObjectIsHeader {
            let newEmptyHeader = T(isEmptyHeader: true)
            newData.insert(newEmptyHeader, at: 0)
        }
        return newData
    }    

    func populate(from data: [T]) {
        self.data = dataWithLeadingEmptyHeader(from: data)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Where my base class now have two new inits:

```
public class BaseCellData: XXX {
    required override public init(isEmptyHeader: Bool) {
        super.init()
        isHeader = true
        self.isEmptyHeader = isEmptyHeader
    }

    public override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and sub classes now have one new init:

```
public class SelectIconCellData: BaseCellData {
    var iconName: String = ""

    init(text: String, imageName: String) {
        super.init()
        // ...
    }

    required public init(isEmptyHeader: Bool) {
        super.init(isEmptyHeader: isEmptyHeader)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Force casting `newEmptyHeader` as `T` complied at my machine.

```
public class BaseCellData {
    public var isEmptyHeader = false
    public var isHeader = true
    public init(isEmptyHeader: Bool) {
        self.isEmptyHeader = isEmptyHeader
    }
}

public class CellDataCollection<T: BaseCellData> {
    private var data = [T]()

    func populate(from data: [T]) {
        self.data.append(contentsOf:data)
        let firstObjectIsHeader = data.first?.isHeader ?? false
        if !firstObjectIsHeader {
            let newEmptyHeader = BaseCellData(isEmptyHeader: true)
            // Safer approach
            if let newEmptyHeader = newEmptyHeader as? T {
                self.data.insert(newEmptyHeader, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except this would cause a runtime exception if T is anything other than `BaseCellData`. Thus making the generic useless.

Comment: Yes, agreed. using specific type in generics fails the generics as whole.

Comment: Unfortunately crashes at runtime

Comment: I removed the force unwrap. But still i do not know the implementation you are trying to do. Maybe you need to look at generics again to resolve the issue, @TristanBurnside mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Your array of T is a specific type where as BaseCellData is more general.

For example say you had these classes:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog: Animal {}
class Cat: Animal {}
```

And you created an array of dogs, obviously you could not add a cat or an animal to it

```
var dogs = [Dog]
dogs.append(Cat()) // Not allowed
dogs.append(Animal()) // Also not allowed
```

So if you have a generic:

```
class AnimalCollection<T:Animal> {
    var animals: [T]
}
```

Then if you create a collection the type of T is whatever you define as the generic type. So for:

```
let dogCollection: AnimalCollection<Dog>
```

The array is of type Dog, and as we saw before adding an animal or a cat to it would not be allowed.

Comment: Yes, I see where I thought wrong in my code. I am trying to insert a baseclass into a list of specific T type. I have rethink my solution.